# searchTwitter timestamps

Tags: r, twitter

I am using the `twitteR` library in R and wondering if is is possible to get timestamps associated with a search or a timeline for that matter. E.G if searching #rstats using searchTwitter, I would like to know when the tweets were made...are there additional parameters I need to parse in order to get that information?

here is some example code...

```
library(twitteR)
searchTwitter("#rstats",n=10)
```

giving the following result

```
[[1]]
[1] "MinneAnalytics: @thomaswdinsmore RT @erikriverson: Some thoughts from an observer on the #Rstats track at #BigDataMN. http://t.co/i42PEQHz #R at #CSOM"

[[2]]
[1] "pentalibra: My package ggdendro to draw dendrograms with ggplot2 is back on CRAN. http://t.co/gMviOSnQ Wait a day or so for Windows binary/ #rstats"

[[3]]
[1] "Lachamadice: RT @freakonometrics: \"Regression tree using Gini's index\" http://t.co/tUplMqQj with #rstats"

[[4]]
[1] "Rbloggers: Tracking Number of Historical Clusters: \n(This article was first published on   Systematic Investor » R,... http://t.co/jRnWUQ2Y #rstats"

[[5]]
[1] "Rbloggers: ggplot2 multiple boxplots with metadata: \n(This article was first published on   mintgene » R, and kindl... http://t.co/re2gghTx #rstats"

[[6]]
[1] "Rbloggers: Learning R using a Chemical Reaction Engineering Book: Part 3: \n(This article was first published on   N... http://t.co/agCJi9Rr #rstats"

[[7]]
[1] "Rbloggers: Learning R using a Chemical Reaction Engineering Book: Part 2: \n(This article was first published on   N... http://t.co/2qqpgQrq #rstats"

[[8]]
[1] "Rbloggers: Waiting for an API request to complete: \n(This article was first published on   Recology - R, and kindly... http://t.co/MZzxHVdw #rstats"

[[9]]
[1] "heidelqekhse3: RT @geospacedman: Just got an openlayers map working on an #rstats #shiny app at #nhshd but... meh."

[[10]]
[1] "jveik: Slides and replay of “Using R with Hadoop” webinar now available #rstats #hadoop | @scoopit http://t.co/Ar2F7We3"
```

Comment: Here's how you figure out the answer: The value section of `?searchTwitter` tells you it returns a `status` object and provides a link to `?status-class` which tells you what is returned. (the "created" field looks like the one you want).  The `?status-class` page also advises you to see `?setRefClass` if it's not clear enough.  Alternatively, you could look at `str(searchTwitter("#rstats", n=10))` to see what is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after a google:

```
 mytweet <- searchTwitter("#chocolate",n=10)
 str(mytweet[[1]])

Reference class 'status' [package "twitteR"] with 10 fields
 $ text        : chr "The #chocolate part of the #croquette. #dumplings #truffles http://t.co/Imwt3tTP"
 $ favorited   : logi FALSE
 $ replyToSN   : chr(0) 
 $ created     : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2013-01-27 16:26:03"
 $ truncated   : logi FALSE
 $ replyToSID  : chr(0) 
 $ id          : chr "295568362526896128"
 $ replyToUID  : chr(0) 
 $ statusSource: chr "&lt;a href=&quot;http://instagr.am&quot;&gt;Instagram&lt;/a&gt;"
 $ screenName  : chr "tahiatmahboob"
 and 33 methods, of which 22 are possibly relevant:
   getCreated, getFavorited, getId, getReplyToSID, getReplyToSN, getReplyToUID, getScreenName, getStatusSource, getText, getTruncated,
   initialize, setCreated, setFavorited, setId, setReplyToSID, setReplyToSN, setReplyToUID, setScreenName, setStatusSource, setText,
   setTruncated, toDataFrame
```

So time stamp is:

```
mytweet[[1]]$created
[1] "2013-01-27 16:26:03 UTC"
```

Never used `twitteR` until I read your question.  Seems like something fun to do when bored.

Answer (score 1):

One alterantive to parse the result( as the answer above) , is to use argument **since** and **until**.

For example you can do :

```
 res <- searchTwitter("#rstats",n=1000,since='2013-01-24',
                                       until='2013-01-28')
```

The `searchTwitter` is a wrapper to the JSON API of twitter. Take a look [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) for more details of the argument and example of the JSON results.